# C# split string containing 'GO' keyword into multiple sql statements

Tags: c#, ssms

If I open SQL Management Studio and write the following text:

```
select a =1
GO
select b =2
```

SQL Management Studio splits the text into two statements, striping on the 'GO' keyword.

How should I do the same thing in C#?
I could use a regex, or string splitting, but I'm not able to split correctly a string like this:

```
select text ='
this is a unique statement
GO
'
```

Comment: Why wouldnt `var statements = mystring.Split("Go");` work? Created an array of strings split by the GO keyword.

Comment: Why are you parsing SQL in C#?  There may be a better way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: Regex would be better than `string.Split` since SQL is case insensitive.

Comment: Use: `Regex.Split(inputString, "GO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: Be great to know what you're really trying to do. Are you trying to send multiple queries in separate batches?

Comment: You have to *parse* SQL in order *not to split* on `'GO'` (string), `[GO]`, `-- GO` comment etc.

Comment: my goal is to process .sql files like sql management studio: split string strategies could break script. i didn't know 'ServerConnection' class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you already know, GO is the default batch separator in SQL management studio, not a SQL keyword.

However management studio has library's available that you can use in C#.
Explained [here](https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/c-executing-batch-t-sql-scripts-with-go-statements/) (option 2)

```
string connectionString, scriptText;
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
ServerConnection svrConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
Server server = new Server(svrConnection);
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scriptText);
```

This will execute "scriptText" as if you execute it in management studio. and it will handle "GO" as a batch separator by default.